# What does "on entering" mean?

Tags: phrase-meaning

> You will then see three doors, which can be easily opened, for the keys are in all the locks. ***On entering*** the first of the chambers, to which these doors lead, you will see a large chest, standing in the middle of the floor.

"***On entering***"? What does that mean?
"***As soon as I entered*** the first of  chambers"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"On X", where X is a gerund/progressive participle (*-ing* form) is, here, an adverbial of time, meaning that it indicates *when* something happened/happens. It indicates that it happens at the point of doing whatever is indicated by X.

That is to say, in the example it means that you will see a large chest as you enter the chamber. Not immediately after entering, but in the process of entering.

Comment: To make it easier to understand for an English language learner, you could say: it is basically a more formal way of saying "When you enter the first of the chambers ..."

Comment: @fred2: I added a little more in an attempt to clarify.